How to specify logging file with date in spring application.properties file
I am trying to use logging.file.name in application.properties file to log my application based on date but I can not get current date. I have tried
logging.file.name=logs/LogFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log

but logs are printed to LogFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log under logs file but not LogFile-2024-05-21.log. How can I specify log file name with current date.
P.S.: I use lombok's @Log4j2 annotation

Why would you expect your properties file or the simple read of a property from it to format a date for you?

What logging backend are you using: log4j-core or logback-classic? The choice of logging backend and API are independent.

Have you tried setting the
logging.pattern.rolling-file-name=LogFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/logback-rolling-files-example

Try setting the following setting:
logging.pattern.rolling-file-name=LogFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log

source https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/logback-rolling-files-example
